# take combobox selected value as a key for dataTemplate of another control wpf

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, controls

i have a combobox :

```
   <Grid>

    <ComboBox Height="52" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              ItemsSource="{Binding templatesNames}"
              SelectedValuePath="Type.FullName"         
              Margin="169,43,0,0" Name="comboBox1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" />

    <Button Content="Button"
   ***Template="{Binding key = Converter={Binding SelectedItem.Value,ElementName=comboBox1}}"
            Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="191,204,0,0" Name="button1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
</Grid>
```

the problem is signed with ***
I have templatesNames how holds names of templates 
I want to covert those names into key whom the button is about to bind to (template keys )

how can I do it ?...
what should the converter do ? does it needed ? can I not use it ?

EDIT:
this is what i do now :

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" 
                               Margin="553,0,0,13" 
                              SelectedValuePath="Type.FullName" SelectedIndex="1"
                              FontFamily="Buxton Sketch"
                              FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="231" Height="46"     VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

where collection is        public ObservableCollection  collection  { get; set; }

the button is similer to @Meleak Button and the project namespace is clr-namespace:dinamicGridLayout
should i write inside the converter Uri resourceLocater = new Uri(@"clr-namespace:dinamicGridLayout;ResourceDictionary1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all your ControlTemplates in a Resource Dictionary you can use a Converter for the Template like this

```
<ComboBox Height="52" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding templatesNames}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Type.FullName"          
          Margin="169,43,0,0" Name="comboBox1"  
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" /> 

<Button Content="Button" 
        Template="{Binding SelectedItem.Value,
                           ElementName=comboBox1,
                           Converter={StaticResource TemplateConverter}}"
        Height="56" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
        Margin="191,204,0,0" Name="button1"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" />
```

And in the Converter you load the ControlTemplate from the Resource Dictionary and return it.

```
public class TemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string resourceKey = value.ToString();
        Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/YourNamespace;component/Dictionary1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
        return resourceDictionary[resourceKey] as ControlTemplate;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update**

If your namespace is dinamicGridLayout then the converter should look like this

```
Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/dinamicGridLayout;component/Dictionary1.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
```

Small sample project uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?aars2ws4oaqhyj0).

Comment: it's seems right but two q :
1.StaticResource ?? are you cretin about it ?
2./YourNamespace;component/Dictionary1.xaml" let's assume my name space is xxxx should it be "clr-namespace:xxx;Dictionary1.xaml"?